# Is there a NSA backdoor in ubuntu desktop os?

Tags: xubuntu, security

I heard talk of selinux being in ubuntu and it being a nsa backdoor.
[Source of my worrying :(](http://forum.prisonplanet.com/index.php?topic=43629.80)

So are these guys right? Is there a backdoor in Ubuntu (I use xubuntu if that matters)?

Have any of you guys ever checked ubuntu/xubuntu source for NSA backdoors?
I would but I don't know how.

Comment: This question will probably be closed as being opinion based. You can however check out an [omgubuntu's article on the issue](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/11/nsa-ask-linus-torvalds-include-backdoors-linux-father-says-yes).

Comment: From your link: "The SELinux is not secret closed code.
So please don't post about "backdoors" with out proof.

The lack of logic makes us all look stupid and paranoid."

Comment: I'm talking about ubuntu not the linux kernal in general though,ubuntu has a rep for putting ads and big brothering people.

Comment: >chili555 Can I trust what that guy said? I'm just trying to get a second opinion.

Comment: [Reflections on Trusting Trust](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/ken/trust.html) is 30 years old.

Comment: Ubuntu uses AppArmor, - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux - the bottom section about AppArmor, so would only be a matter of the kernel in general at this point.

Comment: Okay I thought that ubuntu used selinux .-. thanks for the help I feel better now.

Comment: By the way: selinux is not a backdoor. It is a frontdoor :+

Comment: Please do some research before posting here. That does not mean the baseless ramblings of people on random forums. Read [something](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/42398) written by someone who knows what they're talking about. In any case, this has nothing to do with Ubuntu, as such, if anything it is a kernel and/or SELinux issue.

Comment: >"By the way:selinux is not a backdoor, it is a frontdoor:+ "Awesome Thanks for the help guys, My question was stupid but I got smart answers nontheless.

Comment: lol -10 rep from this question ._.

Comment: You can always delete it and go for the peer pressure badge ;)

Comment: I cant delete it because it has a answer :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few points:

- SELinux isn't included in Ubuntu by default but it is installable
- Ubuntu uses [AppArmor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor) by default (does roughly the same job)
- The NSA working on code does not translate to "The NSA leaving backdoors everywhere"
- The NSA is responsible for helping the US government have secure computers and making SELinux the best it possibly could be would aid that goal. Punching holes in SELinux would be a *monumentally* stupid idea.
- A few people bickering in a forum thread without evidence is not a viable security threat
- I've just seen your comment drawing parallels between this and the Amazon integration. Don't conflate the issue of privacy and advertising with unknown security threats. They're very different beasts.

Are there *known* backdoors in the code? Of course not... Linux is used all over the place and a publicly known issue like that would be too devastating to leave in.

But *could* there be some? Sure. It's impossible to say that every line of code submitted has had security analysis but at the very least (and this is the security boon that most new FOSS advocates allude to) *you* can inspect the code if you're suspicious and then track the provenance. You can also *hope* that other people have reviewed the code. You don't have that choice or hope in close-source software.

As with everything, you just have to work on who you trust most... This isn't something local to SELinux. Consider your entire software stack, but if you're too paranoid you'll very quickly end up not using any software at all.

Comment: Great answer, I thought they included SElinux by default...I feel much better now.